# c2447 error learning to create a win32 window

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I've tried multiple times and copied this code from a video almost the same some is a little different at the moment because I've fooled around without getting new errors but I've been trying to figure this out myself for a few days on and off. Anyways it's c2447 missing { (old style format?) seems like an easy solve after googling but I'm stuck and getting frustrated. also it should be a win32 window

```
#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK
MainWindowCallback(HWND Window
UINT Message,
                              WPARAM WParam,
                              LPARAM LParam);
{
            LRESULT Result = 0;

            switch(Message)
            {
                case WM_SIZE:
                {
                OutputDebugStringA("WM_SIZE\n")
                } break;

                case WM_DESTROY:
                {
                OutputDebugStringA("WM_DESTROY\n")
                } break;

                case WM_ClOSE:
                {
                OutputDebugStringA("WM_CLOSE\n")
                } break;

                case WM_ACTIVATEAPP:
                {
                OutputDebugStringA("WM_ACTIVATEAPP\n")
                } break;

                default:
                {
                Result = ;
                } break;
            }
            return(Result);
}

int CALLBACK 
    WinMain(HINSTANCE Instance,
                HINSTANCE PrevInstance,
                LPSTR CommandLine,
                int ShowCode)



{
    WNDCLASS WindowClass = {};

WindowClass.style = CS_OWNDC|CS_HREDRAW|CS_VREDRAW;
WindowClass.lpfnWndProc = MainWindowCallback;
WindowClass.hInstance = Instance ;
  // WindowClass.hIcon;
WindowClass.lpszClassName = "RavelWindowClass";

    if(RegisterClass(&WindowClass));
{
    HWND WindowHandle =
        CreateWindowEx(0,
                                   WindowClass.lpszClassName,
                                    "Ravel",
                                    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW|WS_VISIBLE,
                                    CW_USEDEFAULT,
                                    CW_USEDEFAULT,
                                    CW_USEDEFAULT,
                                    CW_USEDEFAULT,
                                    0,
                                    0,
                                    Instance,
                                    0);

                if(WindowHandle)
                {
                    for(;;)
                    {
                        MSG Message;
                        BOOL MessageResult = GetMessage(&Message, 0, 0, 0);
                        if(MessageResult > 0)
                        {
                            TranslateMessage(&Message);
                            DispatchMessage(&Message);

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
}

    return(0);
}
```

ps isn't as sloppy in my writer I had trouble with the site.
thx

Comment: Too few commas after `HWND Window`.

Comment: And what's this `Result = ;`

Comment: The comma is actually there in my code, that's weird. 
I filled in Result and I still get the C2447.

Comment: @StevenGosse Can you give us at least the complete error message please? My compiler doesn't have any error like C2447. WTH is it?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s95fcz9b.aspx

Comment: w:\common\base.cpp(8) : error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)

Comment: The reason is that you have a trailing `;` here: `LPARAM LParam);`, try remove that and see if it works.

Comment: error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
error C2065: 'WM_ClOSE' : undeclared identifier
error C2051: case expression not constant
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'

Comment: that's kind of messy but that's what I get when I remove that semi colon

Comment: @StevenGosse - change `WM_ClOSE` to `WM_CLOSE`, notice the case

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a couple of errors. First the compiler error `c2447` tells us:

> The compiler encountered an unexpected open brace at global scope. In
>   most cases, this is caused by a badly-formed function header, a
>   misplaced declaration, or a stray semi-colon. To resolve this issue,
>   verify that the open brace follows a correctly-formed function header,
>   and is not preceded by a declaration or a stray semi-colon.

You get this error because the semi-colon ends your function header, notice that you also missing a `,` between the two first parameters:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK
MainWindowCallback(HWND Window <-- missing comma        
                   UINT Message, 
                   WPARAM WParam, 
                   LPARAM LParam); <-- terminates the function header
```

Notice that c++ is case-sensitive and therefore `WM_ClOSE` is not the same as `WM_CLOSE` which you should be using. In other words you are trying to use an undefined constant and need to change the constants name:

```
case WM_ClOSE: <-- this is an undefined constant, should be WM_CLOSE
{
  OutputDebugStringA("WM_CLOSE\n")
} break;
```